# How to reset a text box using a function tag

Tags: javascript, function

I want to reset the text box ('txt') via an onclick. My virtual keyboard is set up in a table and not a form?

this is the text box

```
<td align='center' bgcolor='red' colspan=3> <input type='text' id='txt'></td>
```

this is the reset

```
<td style='color:#000000' align='center' bgcolor='red' id='myFunction()'onclick='clear()'>Reset</td>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
function clear(){ document.getElementById("txt").value=""; }
```

Comment: Looks like that code should work. Must be a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to clear an input when user click the `<td>`?

You can just add a function like this:

```
function clear(ID)
{
    document.getElementById(ID).value = "";
}
```

Then change your onclick event in `<td>` like this:

```
onclick='clear("txt")'
```

So it'll set the value of `#txt` to empty.

**EDIT:** Didn't see your edit while I typing this answer,

I suggest that you can open the  javascript console or devoloper tools in your browser.